# Getting a NameError when running sqlclear with Django

Tags: django

I am trying to add a foreign key to my Word class. I have just added "doodle" with it's foreign key.
When I do any commands, including sqlclear, I get the following error: `doodle = models.ForeignKey(Drawing, related_name="doodle")
NameError: name 'Drawing' is not defined`

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Word(models.Model):
    doodle = models.ForeignKey(Drawing, related_name="doodle")
    word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    definition = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.word)

class Drawing(models.Model):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name="drawings")
    doodle = models.TextField()
    flags = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    kudos = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: have you delete your database and sync it again when you add that ForeignKey Drawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `sqlclear`, or any other management command. It's simply a Python error: you have referenced `Drawing` in your ForeignKey without defining it. Since it's defined after you use it, you can get around that by putting it in quotes: `'Drawing'`.

I would question though whether you really want ForeignKeys going in both directions between Word and Drawing - that rarely makes sense.

Comment: The reason I added it in both directions is that I am trying to add a new "doodle" which is associated with a word. With no luck.